# Why are the lengths of hashes always multiples of 16

Tags: hash

I don't seem to find an answer that I can understand to the question of why hashes tend to have the multiple of 16 characters. For example: SHA-512 has 128 characters, SHA-256 has 64 characters, MD5 has 32 characters etc. What might be the case for that?

Comment: Everything in computers boils down to the same fundamentals, one on which is memory is measured in multiples of powers of two. If you implement a HashMap and decide you can store the keys in 32 bits then you choose the best hashing algorithm that generates 32 bits. Why 32 bits? Because that's what the largest integer size natively supported by CPU operations is on the architecture you're implementing for.

Comment: Some don't.   SHA-224, for example, is 28 bytes.  RIPEMD-160 and SHA-1 were 20 bytes.

Comment: Sergiu, that’s prejudice, not any particular computer fundamental. I started programming on a computer with 60 bit words.

Comment: @gnasher729 sure, agree, should have written "Everything in most modern computers" instead.